# Piecewise Fourier series with jump discontinuity

Tags: fourier-series, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I'm asked to find the Fourier series expansion, valid on $]-\pi,\pi[$ for the function:

$f(x)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & -\pi < x\leq 0 \\
      cos(x) & 0< x <\pi\\
\end{array} 
\right. $

And also the sum of the series for $x=p \cdot \pi$ for $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now; I understand that the function has a 'jump discontinuity' at x=0, where $cos(0)=1 \neq 0$. And the average value here, which the Series converges to is $\frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}=\frac{cos(0)+0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

But I am fairly inexperienced with such series, and I don't feel that my textbook elucidates it very well. For finding the coefficients... do I add $\frac{1}{2}$? Or is it simply that $a_0=\frac{1}{2}$ and the remaining $a_n$'s are zero? (Since $\int_{0}^{\pi}cos(x)\cdot cos(nx) = 0$)

And with regards to $b_n$ does it follow the normal formula? I.e.
$b_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}cos(x)\cdot sin(nx)$?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Actually $a_0=0$ and $a_1$ is non zero ($\frac{1}{2}$) while half of the $b$'s are zero - the formulas are correct except that you have to divide by $\pi$ each integral; so you will get $.5\cos x$ plus terms with inverse quadratic(in $n$) coefficients in $\sin (nx)$  for $n$ of a specific parity only - try figure it out now

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I wound up with $a_0=0$ and, as you said, $a_n=\frac{1}{2}$. The $b_n$'s were a little harder, but with partiel integration I wound up with:

$b_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n}$ which, as you say, equals zero half the time, and $\frac{2}{n}$ the other half.

I was then asked to calculate the sum of the series for $x=p \cdot \pi$ for $p \in \mathbb{z}$. The sin(n x) is always zero then, so the sum is:

$sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} cos(n p x) = $sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2}=0

Right?

Comment: P.s. When I use a cas tool to plot $\sum_{n=1}^{N} (\frac{1}{2}cos(nx)+\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n}sin(nx))$ I get a pretty wonky looking graph, that most certainly does not approach 0 for $x>0$. Also; was it only $a_n1$ that was $\frac{1}{2}$? Or is it all the $a_n$'s?

Comment: $a_n$ has to be zero when $n \ne 1$; note that if you consider $g(x)=\cos x, -\pi < x < 0, 0$ rest, we have $f+g=\cos x$, $f-g$ odd so only a sine series hence $f=\frac{1}{2} \cos x +$ sine series; in particular $f(p\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$